# React-Router-4 routing from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Is it possible to route a component from another component?

So normally it would be done like below

```
<NavLink to="/link">link</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/anotherLink">link </NavLink>
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/link" component={linkComponent}/>
    <Route path="/anotherLink" component={anotherLinkComponent}/>
</Switch>
```

but is it possible to have NavLink in one component which is loaded in the main component then route from the main component? So have `NavLink` in one component and have `Route` in the main component.

The Nav component

```
export default class Nav extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="navigation">
                <ul className="nav-container">
                    <li>
                        <NavLink to="/" className="nav-title">
                            First Page
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink to="second-page" className="nav-title">
                            Second Page
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink to="third-page" className="nav-title">
                            Third Page
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div className="nav-decoration">

                </div>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}
```

The App component

```
import Nav from 'whateverthepath';

export default class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Nav/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Firstpage}/>
                    <Route path="/secondpage" component={Secondpage}/>

                </Switch>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

All the appropriate React imports are done

Comment: So long as a Route matching a Link's destination is within the visible rendered hierarchy, React Router will render it. Your example should work, you need to wrap the `App` within a `Router` and try it.

Answer (score 0):

That's definitely possible and your example should even work as is. The biggest thing you'll need to make sure of is that your `<Route>`s were rendered as some point. The reason your example works is because you're rendering `<Nav>` in the same render() method as your `<Switch>` statement. If you were to instead just render `<Nav>` without ever rendering the switch statement, then the NavLinks would take you somewhere that React Router hasn't been informed about. That's typically why your `<Route>`s are almost always in your most parent component, to make sure they're rendered.